# Why the timer has no effect?

Tags: java, animation, timer

I need to make a simple animation in java but there's something I don't understand about Timers.

```
public class Gra extends JPanel{

Oval oval1;
Timer timer;

Gra(){
    this.setBackground(Color.black);

    oval1 = new Oval();
    timer = new Timer(true);
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            oval1.movement();
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> repaint());
        }
    }, 1);
}
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
           super.paintComponent(g);
           g.setColor(oval.kolor);
                g.fillOval(oval.x, oval.y, 2*oval.r1, 2*oval.r2);
    }
}
```

And then nothing happens. The oval is created and drawed once, but it doesn't move.

Comment: You mustn't call swing functions from another thread. Use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> repaint());` if you call swing methods in `
repaint()`. 
Could you please post the code of `repaint()`?

Comment: I used this instead of "repaint()" and nothing changed.

Comment: Can you share the code of the whole class?

Comment: Ok, this is it.

Comment: You should use the Swing timer and not the java.util.Timer.  And you don't need to invoke repaint on the EDT because repaint simply schedules a repaint operation to run on that thread.

Comment: Fixed, thanks very much. All beacuse of wrong library.